# Select last child, and ensure it is not the only child?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to wrap a div around content only if it is the last-child. The problem I have with this code is that it will execute if there is only one item. So i want to know how I should check to use the :last-child only when there are mor than one children. If there is only one child. I do not want the div added. Here is my code:

```
$('div[class^="columns-"]').each(function(){
   $(this).find('div[class^="column"]:last-child').each(function(i){
       $(this).wrapInner('<div class="col-last" />');   
   });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).find(' * + ...` makes sure the element has a sibling before it http://jsfiddle.net/cMEeu/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the only child, it's also the first one so you can do:

```
$('div[class^="columns-"]').each(function(){
   $(this).find('div[class^="column"]:last-child:not(:first-child)').each(function(i){
       $(this).wrapInner('<div class="col-last" />');   
   });
});
```

This way you can have multiple sets of columns and still get only the last child of the sets with more than one column in them, i.e. if you have:

```
<div class="row-1">
  <div class="columns-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-2">
  <div class="columns-1"></div>
  <div class="columns-2"></div>
  <div class="columns-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-3">
  <div class="columns-1"></div>
</div>
```

the selector will only affect .row-2 .columns-3

Comment: +1 Kudos for the great approach, and without extra conditional statements!

Comment: the :last-child, :first-child, and not() selectors can be pretty slow. This won't be a good solution if you have a lot of parents or children.

Comment: Actually now when I looked at it, the whole thing can be done like this: `$('div[class^="columns-"] > div[class^="column"]:last-child:not(:first-child)').wrapInner('<div class="col-last" />');`. This could speed up things a little, because almost all operations are done within jQuery. There aren't many other ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this using [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('div[class^="columns-"]').each(function(){
    $(this).find('div[class^="column"]:last-child')
    .filter(function(){ return $(this).parent().children().length > 1; )
    .each(function(i){
        $(this).wrapInner('<div class="col-last" />');   
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5ueV/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('div[class^="columns-"]').each(function(){
     if((this).children().length>1)
       $(this).
           find('div[class^="column"]:last-child').
           each(function(i){
               $(this).wrapInner('<div class="col-last" />');   
           });
 });
```

`children().length` this will give the no of child elements

Comment: `children.length` and not `children().length`, also I made an example for this working (after the changes)

Comment: I mean, either `(this).children.length` or `$(this).children().length`, both work

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('div[class^="columns-"]').each(function() {
    var children = $(this).find('div[class^="column"]');
    if(children.length > 1) {
        children.last().wrapInner('<div class="col-last" />');   
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`* + selector` [selects only elements preceded by an element](http://jsfiddle.net/cMEeu/2/)

`:gt(0)` [selects all elements that are not first](http://jsfiddle.net/cMEeu/5/)

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/